# Config File using Environment Variables

Tags: c++, configuration

I have a .cfg file and I'd like to use an environment variable to configure one of the fields.

`directory=${HOME}/folder1/`

However, when I parse this config, it's reading `${HOME}` as a string, which is obviously not what I want.

I wrote my own parser in C++, in case I need to do something special. Right now it is a very basic read and parse.

```
void Config_Parser::parse_config_by_delimiter(string config, string delimiter) {
   ifstream infile(config);
   while (infile >> line) {
      key = line.substr(0, line.find(delimiter));
      value = line.substr(line.find(delimiter)+1);
      if (this->config_settings.find(key) != this->config_settings.end()) {
         cout << "Cannot use config... same key is set multiple times" << endl;
      }
      this->config_settings.insert({key, value});
   }
}
```

The code seems to work fine for all other config settings (anything not using an environment variable), so I don't think its a problem with the code. But, I am a C++ noobie, so it's here anyways.

When I parse and print out the value:

Actual output: `${HOME}/folder1/`

Expected/desired output: `/home/my_dir/folder1/`

Answer (score 0):

*Untested*

You can use `wordexp` to do posix shell-like expansion of strings.

> The function wordexp() performs a shell-like expansion of the string
>          s and returns the result in the structure pointed to by p.

You will need to `#include <wordexp.h>`

You also probably want to specify the flag `WRDE_NOCMD` to prevent subshell command execution.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the following configuration syntax acceptable to you?

```
directory = getenv("HOME") + "/folder1/";
```

If so, then a configuration file parser library I wrote called Config4* can do what you want. You can find it on http://www.config4star.org.

I recommend you scroll down the web page to "Download the Manuals" and retrieve *Config4* Getting Started Guide* and *Config4* C++ API Guide*. Chapters 2 (overview of syntax) and 3 (overview of API) of the "Getting Started" guide should be more than sufficient to get you up and running.